# new column which has the values from another two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

column d is the expected output

```
a                  b             c             d 
2009-04-01        0.42         null           null 
2009-04-02        0.3          null           null 
.
.
2010-03-16        1.2         2009-04-01       1.2 - 0.42 
2010-03-17        0.7         2009-04-02       0.7 - 0.3
```

the values of column d should be calculated as:
for every row look at the date in column a then take the value from column b and subtract the value which corresponds in b 
for the date in column c .

I have a table which has a b c

select a, b, c from mytable
 Should i make a self join?

```
something like

select 
 t1.a
,t1.b
,t1.c
,t2.b -t1.b as d 
into #myTemptable
from (
select
 a 
,b
,c 
from mytable 
)
join (
select 
 a
,b
,c 
from #myTemptable
)
on -- i am not sure how to join them here, ideas?
```

Sorry for the title, I don't know which would be appropiate here. Any solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try;

```
select
    t.a, t.b, t.c, 
    case when t1.b is null then null
    else t.b - t1.b  end as d
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t.c = t1.a
```

Comment: thank you. I have have something i don't understand.I used your code and I placed this into a temp table, but in there now i have 16627680 lines and in my original table i had 180576. How can i make sure the same number of lines will be inserted. And I also have other columns in the table, but for the sake of simplicity i left them out, they are not relevant to the calculation of the column D

Comment: Its because you have duplicate data in `a` and `c` column.

Comment: i have another column "i" which goes has values from 1 to 108, and for each of those values i have what i described above. How can I filter them somehow so i would keep my number of lines?

Comment: probably i have to somehow loop through I and for every value above, your query should be performed, right?. Or i also have to join them on I?

Comment: Its about selection.... If you have 2 values for same `a` which  one you have to select???

Comment: i was thinking like this: left join mytable t1 on t.c = t1.a and t1.i = t.i   , that should work, right? that way i only have 1 value for a. Now, i no longer have duplicated but the problem is the result is not right.

Comment: `t.c = t1.a and t1.i = t.i` will only select rows having `c = a` if `i` is a unique key, i believe that is not what you want...

Comment: Now it's working as it should! thank you a lot, been trying for couple of hours now. All the values are calculated corectly but it trimmed my table to 153950 lines, i'm missing @30000 lines using this